# how to do this , append html to other dropdown?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, if-statement, return, dropdown

I will make it in simple way I want to "return" in the if that inside if

```
if(condition){
    ...
       if(another_condition)
         {
           ...
               return;//I want this "return" return from the first if also
         } 
}
```

actually I have complex script for me to do , I have liste of content like this generated from document docx...:
chapitre1
I. title1
   1)subtitle1
   2)subtitle2
II.title2
  1)subtitle1
  2)subtitle2
  3)subtitle3
chapitre2
I.title1
  etc

first I want to separate the grand title for each chapter with [dropdown hover](http://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/) style.
I want the script to append the content of each chapter in other dropdown and each grand title to another sub dropdown like dropdown hover style

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6Iul.png)

Comment: HUH? Not sure what you are asking. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: It already will...

Comment: `return` returns from the *whole function*, not just an `if` block. If it's not working for you, there's more to your problem. Closures you're not showing, for example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess you don't really mean `return`, you just want to break out of the body of the outer `if`.

Don't do that. Instead, either:

1. Use `else`, putting all the rest of the body of the outer `if`'s block in the `else` block, or
2. Break up your logic into smaller pieces, wrap them in functions, and then combine those functions. That typically removes the need for this kind of convoluted logic.

`else` example:

```
if (someCondition) {
    doThis();
    if (someOtherCondition) {
        doThat();
    } else {
        doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function doThis() { console.log("doThis"); }
function doThat() { console.log("doThat"); }
function doSomethingElse() { console.log("doSomethingElse"); }

function foo(someCondition, someOtherCondition) {
    if (someCondition) {
        doThis();
        if (someOtherCondition) {
            doThat();
        } else {
            doSomethingElse();
        }
    }
    console.log("foo done");
}

console.log("foo(true, false):");
foo(true, false);
console.log("foo(true, true):");
foo(true, true);
```

---

Having said that: JavaScript *does* actually let you use a directed `break` in `if` statements, unlike many other languages. So you could do:

```
// REALLY BAD PRACTICE
outer:
if (someCondition) {
    doThis();
    if (someOtherCondition) {
        doThat();
        break outer;
    }
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

In that, if both `someCondition` and `someOtherCondition` are true, `doSomethingElse` will never be called.

Live Example:

```js
function doThis() { console.log("doThis"); }
function doThat() { console.log("doThat"); }
function doSomethingElse() { console.log("doSomethingElse"); }

function foo(someCondition, someOtherCondition) {
    outer:
    if (someCondition) {
        doThis();
        if (someOtherCondition) {
            doThat();
            break outer;
        }
        doSomethingElse();
    }
    console.log("foo done");
}

console.log("foo(true, false):");
foo(true, false);
console.log("foo(true, true):");
foo(true, true);
```

But....don't do that. :-)

Comment: *(If you see `break outer;` in the **`else`** example above, hit refresh. Editing error.)*

Comment: actually my problem is I have document generated to html with liste   of content like mentioned above and I want with javascript to generate that list of content in [link](http://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/) style ... I appended the dropdown with javascript  my problem i cannot how to separate the content of  chapter into different dropdown

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return *the result of the function you're inside of*, just use 'return' like normal.

If you want to *avoid executing the rest of the code inside the first if*, you could set up an external variable, something like:

```
if (first condition) {
    var continue = true;
    if (second condition) {
        ...
        continue = false;
    }

    if (continue) {
        ....
    }
}
```